# How do I speed up 'watching' multiple arrays with the same data in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

A large amount of data (+-15 000 records) is loaded via AJAX which is then used to populate two arrays, one sorted by ID the other by a name. Both the arrays contains the same objects just ordered differently.

The data is displayed in a tree view but the hierarchy can be changed by the user. The tree is virtualised on the first level so only the records displayed + 50% is 'materialized' as vue components.

Supplying both of the arrays as data to a vue instance is very slow. I suspect vue.js is adding observers to the objects twice, or change notifications is sent multiple times, I don't really know.

So only one of the arrays is added to vue the other is used out of band.

Vue slows down the addition of elements to an array a lot. If the array is populated before it is bound to the vue instance it takes +-20s before the tree view is displayed. If I bind it before populating the arrays it takes about +-50s before the tree view becomes usable (the elements are displayed almost instantly). This could be because of notifications going for all these elements added.

1. Is there a way to add a second array with duplicate data so vue.js watches it for changes, but it doesn't slow vue down as much?
2. Is there a way to switch watching/notifications of temporarily so elements could be added to an array without the penalty, yet be 'watched' when notifications is switched back on?

I'm not sure that my reasoning behind the slowdowns is correct, so maybe my questions are misguided.

O another thing I need the arrays to be watched and only one of the properties of the elements.

```
var recordsById = [];
var recordsByName = [];

// addRecord gets called for every record AJAX returns, so +-15 000
// calling addRecord 15 000 times before 'binding' takes 20 sec (20 sec with no display)
// calling addRecord after 'binding' takes > 50 sec (instant display but CPU usage makes treeview unausable)
function addRecord(record) {
  var pos = binarySearch(recordsById, record);
  recordsById.splice(0, pos, record);
  pos = binarySearch(recordsByName, record);
  recordsByName.splice(0, pos, record);
}

var treeView = new Vue({
  el: '#treeView',
  data: {
    // If I uncomment following line, vue becomes very slow, not just for initial loading, but as a whole
    //recordsById: recordsById, 
    recordsByName: recordsByName
  },
  computed: {
    virtualizedList: function() {.....}
  }
})
```

Comment: How are the elements added? Using `push`? Assigning the whole array at once?

Comment: @Roy Using insert, the arrays are sorted.

Comment: Can you give some code to illustrate in a simple way how the arrays are manipulated and how the HTML renders them?

Comment: @Roy Binary search the array to get the appropriate position then insert it there. I now the way I'm inserting data into the array will be somewhat slow. The problem is that it is a lot slower when that array is observed by vue.js, but I need ordered data. I will try adding a batch of presorted data at a time.

Comment: what's your benefit of using two different arrays vs. saving one array and having two computed properties that return the sorted array? (doesn't have much to do with the speed, but it would seem like if the data is the same, it should just be the one array?

Comment: @mvuajua Actually I'd need only one computed property to sort the array differently. But that would require a resort every time the source is updated. Perhaps doing that is not as expensive as I thought.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple techniques which might improve your performance.

## Using the keys

For rendering large lists, the first thing you want to do is [use a `key`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Components-and-v-for). A great candidate for this is the `id` you speak about.

## Use pagination

An obvious solution to "displaying a lot of data is slow" is "display less data". Let's face it, 15 000 *is* a lot. Even if Vue itself could insert and update so many rows quickly, think of the user's browser: will it be able to keep up? Even if it was the simplest possible list of text nodes, it would still be a lot of nodes.

## Use virtual scrolling technique

If you don't like the look of pagination, a more advanced approach would be virtual scrolling. As user browses this large list, dynamically add the elements below, and remove the ones that the user has already seen. You keep the total number of elements from the list at the DOM at once to minimum.

Comment: Thanks @Lazar I already use keys, and virtual scrolling. Problem is actually adding the data to an array which is a data source for a vue.js instance